# RTRIM string ending with an incremental number

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to narrow down the follow string to just the username. The number at the end is always different. I can LTRIM just fine, but when I try to use RTRIM I am having difficulty removing everything to the right of the username.

```
C:\documents and settings\[USERNAME]\my documents\reports\204452.pdf
```

Will RTRIM work in this instance? If not, a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you're already doing, and why it doesn't work. Is the path up to the username always the same - same case, and can't be (for example) on `D:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the username is always the third level of the full path, you can use a regular expression:

```
regexp_substr(<file path>, '[^\\]+', 1, 3)
```

For example:

```
select regexp_substr('C:\documents and settings\[USERNAME]\my documents\reports\204452.pdf', '[^\\]+', 1, 3)
from dual;
```

or using a subquery just to make it more readable:

```
select regexp_substr(file_path, '[^\\]+', 1, 3)
from (
  select 'C:\documents and settings\[USERNAME]\my documents\reports\204452.pdf'
  as file_path
  from dual
);

REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_PATH,'[^\\]+',1,3)
-------------------------------------
[USERNAME]
```

Note that the backslash has to be escaped in the pattern.